# Cannot find my python3 config-dir in order to configure vim with python3 support

Tags: python-3.x, vim, youcompleteme

My end goal is to have the YouCompleteMe Pluggin for Vim. As a prerequiste I need my Vim to be configured for python3.

Previous when configuring with python I used the following command

`./configure --enable-pythoninterp=yes`

From searching it looks like the configure command for python3 is

`./configure --enable-python3interp=yes --with-python3-config-dir=????`

Unfortunately all the search results shows a pathway of `/usr/lib/python3...` No such path exists for me.

I do have python 3, running `which python3` results in `/usr/bin/python3`

How can I find the route to my python3 config dir?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. Something like this file -> /usr/bin/python3.6-config?

Comment: weird, it looks like I have `-config` for the other python versions but not 3

Comment: @Dean Do you have any other thoughts on where the config dir would be, I've tried everything I can think of

Comment: It doesn't work with just `./configure --enable-python3interp=yes`? --with-python-config-dir is deprecated. Or maybe this link can help -> https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18211/configure-vim-with-python-support-for-debian-9-4-vm-instance

Comment: lol Yes thanks @Dean that was actually my post. I have a long history of YCM and compiling Vim for python support. The `--with-python3-command` ended up working with a new version of python3, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up downloading the latest python which was 3.8, then running `which python3` which provided a pathway. Then I used that pathway in this command

```
./configure --enable-python3interp --with-python3-command=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
```

Followed by

```
$ cd src
$ make
$ sudo make install

Over at ycm ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
$ ./install.py --js-completer
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on Mac OS X. So my recommendation is that you should install a package manager such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and use it to install a more featureful Vim on your machine.

After you set up Homebrew, all you need to install Vim with Python3 support is:

```
$ brew install vim
```

Since version 1.6.0 of Homebrew (2018-04-09), Vim from Homebrew includes Python3 support by default.

This is much better than building it yourself from source, because using a package manager ensures you're using a build that is tested and well integrated into your platform. You also get a simple upgrade path to keep up to date with latest versions of Vim. By getting easy upgrades you'll also get security fixes, if there are any.

If you're building from source yourself, you're in theory signing up to do all that yourself, but it's hard to do so as well as a project that's dedicated to do so and has been specializing on building software for years.

So here's a strong recommendation to using a package whenever one is available and steering away from building from source as much as possible.